# Convert a text with special unicode to normal text (java)

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have a text which includes numerous unicode (?) characters in it, like the followings:

passaic$002c new jersey 
Which should be : passaic, new jersey

Albert_W$002E_Barney
Which should be : albert w. barney

Roosevelt_High_School_$0028Yonkers$002C_New_York$0029
which should be: Roosevelt_High_School_(Yonkers,_New_York)

I searched the web and there is a big list of these characters: http://colemak.com/pub/mac/wordherd_source.txt

Do you know any fast method that I can replace these characters with their original characters? Note that I don't want to replace each of these characters one by one (like using replaceAll.) Instead I want to use a function that has already implemented this (maybe an external library)

Answer (score 0):

Try native2ascii tool of java. Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are UTF-16BE encoded values you can just use parse the values and cast to *char*:

```
  public static String parse(CharSequence csq) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\p{XDigit}{4}+)").matcher(csq);
    int last = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
      out.append(csq.subSequence(last, matcher.start()));
      String hex = matcher.group(1);
      char ch = (char) Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
      out.append(ch);
      last = matcher.end();
    }
    out.append(csq.subSequence(last, csq.length()));
    return out.toString();
  }
```